# returning referece of a local string object

Tags: c++

```
string& GetMyStr(string& somestr)
{
   string & str=somestr;
   //do something with str
   return str;
}
```

str is a local object, but why I can still get the value after return ? I think right after the function return, it too is gone and the return value is not referenced. I think I miss it, maybe.

Answer (score 8):

Because you're returning a reference to the argument which exists outside the function. You're taking the argument by reference as `somestr` and then making `str` refer to that object, so `str` is **not** a local object, but a reference to the object that the caller passes to the function.

This creates a reference to the argument passed in:

```
string & str=somestr;
```

Then you return it as a reference. Any operations you do to `str` in the meanwhile are done to `somestr` so the caller's argument is modified.

You'll see that if you print the argument you pass to `GetMyStr` and then print the return value of that call that the strings are the same (or you could just compare the addresses which will also be the same).

Comment: Thank you, but what if I change it into `string str=somestr;` this isn't a reference anymore, right ? Or when the argument passed in isn't a reference, it will still work on my compiler.

Comment: That's correct and you'll end up running into undefined behavior, since you've returned a reference to an object whose lifetime has ended.  It might work by Sheer Dumb Luck, but there's no guarantee.

Comment: @Baby yes that is correct, it's not a reference any more. If you try to return a reference to `str` when you do `string str=somestr;`, then it _will_ be destroyed because you returned a reference to a local object.

Answer (score 1):

`somestr` is a reference, and so refers to an object that's outside `GetMyStr`'s scope. As such, it will still exist after `GetMyStr` returns, allowing you to safely use it. This would have been much different if `somestr` was not a reference, because then you would have returned a reference to a copy of the object (a local variable).

Answer (score 1):

> str is a local object

No, it isn't. The type of `str` is `string&`, so it is a reference. In particular, it refers to the `somestr` that was passed in by reference; that is, to the caller's string. That will obviously still exist after the function returns.

Answer (score 0):

I think I asked a simillar question in the below mentioned thread. You could take a look at this. It became clear to me after a few mins! :) ( although I am discussing about pointers, there is nothing else to get confused about :D)

[Pointer - returning Local reference in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7155991/pointer-returning-local-reference-in-c/7156014#7156014)